# Powershell loop with numbers to alphabet

Tags: powershell, increment, alphabet

I need help with the following:
Create a for loop based on the conditions that the index is initialized to 0, $test is less than 26, and the index is incremented by 1
For each iteration, print the current letter of the alphabet. Start at the letter A. Thus, for each iteration, a single letter is printed on a separate line.
I am not able to increment the char each time the loop runs

```
for ($test = 0; $test -lt 26; $test++)
{
[char]65
}
```

I have tried multiple attempts with trying to increment the char 65 through 90 with no success.
Is there an easier way to increment the alphabet to show a letter for each loop that is ran?

Comment: 0=A 1=B 2=C 3=D ....25=Z

Comment: 0..25 | %{ [char] ($_ + [byte][char] 'A') }

Comment: if all you want it the range of uppercase letters, this will do it ... `[char[]]('A'[0]..'Z'[0])`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can sum your loop index with 65. So, it'll be: 0 + 65  = A, 1 + 65  = B ...

```
for ($test = 0; $test -lt 26; $test++)
{
    [char](65 + $test)
}
```

Comment: for ($test = 0; $test -lt 26; $test++) 
{
$char = [char](65 +$test)
Write-Host $char
}
Your suggestion worked out great. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

PS2 to PS5:

```
97..(97+25) | % { [char]$_ }
```

**Faster**:

```
(97..(97+25)).ForEach({ [char]$_ })
```

PS6+:

```
'a'..'z' | % { $_ }
```

**Faster**:

```
('a'..'z').ForEach({ $_ })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to find the first available drive. It checks drives E to Z, and stops on the first available one:

```
101..(97+25) | % { if(!( get-psdrive ([char]$_ ) -ea 0 ) ) {$freedrive = ([char]$_ ); break} }
$freedrive
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example does not assume 'A' is 65 and also allows you to change it to whatever starting drive you desire. For example, to start with 'C' and go to 'Z':

```
$start = 'C'
for ($next = 0; $next -lt (26 + [byte][char]'A' - [byte][char]$start); $next++) {
    [char]([byte][char]$start + $next)
}
```